# Understanding Fn / FnOnce closures

Tags: rust, closures

In the following example, I don't understand why the first example allows the closure to be `Fn`, but the second only `FnOnce`.

Example 1:

```
fn with_client(
    client: BasicClient,
) -> impl Filter<Extract = (BasicClient,), Error = Infallible> + Clone {
    warp::any().map(move || client.clone())
}
```

Example 2:

```
fn with_client(
    client: BasicClient,
) -> impl Filter<Extract = (BasicClient,), Error = Infallible> + Clone {
    let clone = client.clone();
    warp::any().map(move || clone)
}
```

If I try and run the second example, I get a compiler warning about the closure being `FnOnce` as it needs to move `clone` into the closure. This is certainly the case, but I can't see how this differs from the first example, where we need to move `client` into the closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's desugar the closures manually.

```rust
struct Closure1 {
    client: BasicClient,
}
impl FnOnce<()> for Closure1 {
    type Output = BasicClient;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, (): ()) -> BasicClient {
        <Self as Fn<()>>::call(&self, ())
    }
}
impl FnMut<()> for Closure1 {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, (): ()) -> BasicClient {
        <Self as Fn<()>>::call(&*self, ())
    }
}
impl Fn<()> for Closure1 {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, (): ()) -> BasicClient {
        <BasicClient as Clone>::clone(&self.client)
    }
}

struct Closure2 {
    client: BasicClient,
}
impl FnOnce<()> for Closure2 {
    type Output = BasicClient;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, (): ()) -> BasicClient {
        self.client
    }
}

fn with_client(
    client: BasicClient,
) -> impl Filter<Extract = (BasicClient,), Error = Infallible> + Clone {
    warp::any().map(Closure1 { client })
}

fn with_client(
    client: BasicClient,
) -> impl Filter<Extract = (BasicClient,), Error = Infallible> + Clone {
    let clone = <BaseClient as Clone>::clone(&clone);
    warp::any().map(Closure1 { client: clone })
}
```

Like you see, the problem is not that we move `client` **into** the closure. The problem is that we move it **out of** the closure. When you move out of something, you must have ownership of the data: thus, `FnOnce`. The fact that you're creating the closure with a clone does not matter. But when you clone *inside the closure*, you only use shared references - and thus you don't need ownership, or even exclusive access - thus `Fn`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically because `clone()` is `fn clone(&self) -> Self;`, only a reference of `client` is moved into the closure. Therefore in example 1 the closure can be called multiple times. In example 2 the object `clone` itself is moved into the closure. Since the object is only created once, the closure is `FnOnce`.

If `BasicClient` has another method, say `fn not_clone(self);` , and example 1 calls `warp::any().map(move || client.not_clone())`, the closure will also be a `FnOnce`, because the method consumes `self`. `client` itself, not a reference, is moved into the closure. However if `BasicClient` implements `Copy` trait in addition to `Clone` the compiler will makes a copy and moves the copy into the closure for each invocation of the closure. The `not_clone` closure, as well as the closure in example 2, will be `Fn`.